# Incorrect text from mariadb via python

Tags: python, mysql, encoding, mariadb

I have my mariadb where I have some text on russian language(which I add by `INSERT INTO test VALUES(1, "Абвг Деёжзий", "2138712894-213123", true)`) And I have my python code:

```
import MySQLdb
connection=MySQLdb.connect(user="t", password="t", host="127.0.0.1", database="project")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM test;")
for a,b,c,d in cursor:
    print(a,b,c,d)
```

And as the output I have this:

```
1 ???? ??????? 2138712894-213123 1
```

(Where ???? ??????? is one string with space on russian)
I tried `SET CHARACTER SET utf8` and `SET NAMES utf8` but I didn't have the right output. What should I do to get the text.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the charset option in the connect function..

```
connection=MySQLdb.connect(
   user="t"
 , password="t"
 , host="127.0.0.1"
 , database="project"
 , charset="utf8"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try `SET NAMES utf8`

It works with MYSQL and should work with MariaDB as well.
For the [MariaDB KnowledgeBase](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/set-names/)

> Sets the character_set_client, character_set_connection,
>   character_set_results and, implicitly, the collation_connection
>   session system variables to the specified character set and collation.
>
> This determines which character set the client will use to send
>   statements to the server, and the server will use for sending results
>   back to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Notes on Python:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python

Most notable:  Start the source code with

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

If that does not suffice, follow the tips in [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) for "question marks".

If you need even more debugging, note that the hex encoding for `Абвг` in utf8 (or utf8mb4) is `D090 D0B1 D0B2 D0B3`.